# Python: Converting a dictionary value to a list

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have `d = {"key": (5,4,"val1","val2",2)}` How would I grab val1 out of the tuple and turn it into a list by itself?

Comment: Do you want to do this for multiple keys (with the same tuple format for each value), or just the one key?

Comment: You should really use a data structure of some sort for that big tuple. (Like a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).) Complex ad-hoc tuples shouldn't really be used unless they're broken apart very shortly after they're created. (I.e. when returning multiple values from a function, or as intermediate results in list-munging code that uses comprehensions / `zip()` / etc.)

Comment: i don't get the reason for the downvotes.... Oo it's a valid question and the downvoters could at least explain their actions... Welcome to SO (use operator.itemgetter)

Answer (score 6):

`[d['key'][2]]` should do the trick ...

Breaking it down:

- `d['key']` retieves the tuple from the dictionary
- [2] subscripts the list and gets the desired item out of it
- The outer brackets put the final object into a list

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean simply:

```
list(d['key'][2])
```

Comment: This will give him `['v', 'a', 'l', '1']`, not `['val1']`, which I'm guessing he'll find surprising… but maybe it's what he wants. It's so hard to tell.

Comment: @abanert: I thought OP wanted `['v', 'a', 'l', '1']`. Upon rereading the question, your interpretation seems to make better sense

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a list of the values in that position for *all* keys in your dictionary:

```
[value[2] for value in d.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

values = map(itemgetter(2), d.values())
```

should be the fastest way for big dictioanries.

even if our BDFL doesn't like those map, filter, lambda constructs very much ;-)